# Using setTempo and putSamples in SoundTouch

Tags: soundtouch

Which samples does `SoundTouch::setTempo` affect, those already in the FIFO or those that are going to be put into the FIFO by `SoundTouch::putSamples`? That is, does `SoundTouch::setTempo` commit or prepare a tempo change?